# Solve First Order Linear PDE with Method of Characteristic

Tags: partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

Given a problem

$x^2\,u_x+xy\,u_y=y\,u$

Then, the characteristic equation is

$\dfrac{dx}{x^2}=\dfrac{dy}{xy}=\dfrac{du}{yu}$

From the first two of those equation, i got

$C_1=\dfrac{y}{x}$

How to obtain the other $C_2$? So that i have implicit solution $F(C_1)=C_2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\dfrac{dx}{x^2}=\dfrac{dy}{xy}=\dfrac{du}{yu}$$

From the first two ratio

\begin{align}
\dfrac{dx}{x^2} &= \dfrac{dy}{xy} \\
\implies \dfrac{dx}{x} &= \dfrac{dy}{y} \\
\implies \log x - \log y &= \log c_1 \\
\implies\frac{x}{y} &= c_1
\end{align}

From the last two

\begin{align}
\dfrac{dy}{xy} &= \dfrac{du}{yu} \\
\implies \dfrac{dy}{x} &= \dfrac{du}{u} \\
\implies \dfrac{dy}{c_1y} &= \dfrac{du}{u} \\
\implies \log y &= c_1(\log u - \log c_2) \\
\implies \log y &= \frac{x}{y}\log \left(\frac{u}{c_2} \right) \\
\implies \frac{u}{c_2} &= y^{\frac{y}{x}} \\
\implies c_2 &= uy^{-\frac{y}{x}}
\end{align}

So the  implicit solution is $$F \left(\frac{x}{y} \right)=uy^{-\frac{y}{x}}$$

Comment: Is it different from the first two that is $\frac{x}{y}$ and $\frac{y}{x}$?

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo @user516076

Comment: You can take any one of the ratio, as in both case the value is a constant i.e., you can take $\frac{x}{y}=c_1\quad$ or, $\frac{y}{x}=\frac{1}{c_1}=c_3$

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You are most welcome @user516076